# How to handle two tables with same directives in protractor

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, css-selectors, protractor

I have two tables in the same page with same directives and I want to perform some actions only on the columns present in the second table.

See below html for reference.

```
<table role="presentation" id="gridview-1204-table" class="x-gridview-1204-table x-grid-table x-grid-with-col-lines x-grid-with-row-lines x-grid-table-selected-first x-grid-table-focused-first" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 2274px;" tabindex="-1">
<colgroup>
<col class="x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1124" style="width:24px">
</colgroup>
<colgroup>
<col class="x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1027" style="width:150px">
</colgroup>
<tbody id="gridview-1204-body">
    <tr role="row" id="gridview-1204-record-1998058-null-null" data-boundview="gridview-1204" data-recordid="1998058-null-null" data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused" tabindex="-1">
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1124 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1402">
            <div id="ext-gen1403" unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
            <div class="x-grid-row-checker">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1027 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1404">
            <div id="ext-gen1405" unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
.
.
.
.
.
<div>
<table role="presentation" id="gridview-1057-table" class="x-gridview-1057-table x-grid-table x-grid-with-col-lines x-grid-with-row-lines x-grid-table-selected-first x-grid-table-focused-first" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 2274px;" tabindex="-1">
<colgroup>
<col class="x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1125" style="width:24px">
</colgroup>
<colgroup>
<col class="x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1028" style="width:150px">
</colgroup>
<tbody id="gridview-1057-body">
    <tr role="row" id="gridview-1057-record-1998058-null-null" data-boundview="gridview-1057" data-recordid="1998058-null-null" data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused" tabindex="-1">
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1125 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1402">
            <div id="ext-gen1403" unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
            <div class="x-grid-row-checker">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1028 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1404">
            <div id="ext-gen1405" unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1029 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1406">
            <div id="ext-gen1407" unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Say, I would like to click on third column of the second table. With below code, I'm unable to click on the element.

```
let reqTable = element(by.xpath('(//tr[contains(@role,"row")][contains(@data-boundview,"gridview")])[2]'));
let reqcolumn = reqTable.element(by.xpath('//td[3]/div'));
reqcolumn.click();
```

Even tried

```
element(by.xpath('(//tr[contains(@role,"row")][contains(@data-boundview,"gridview")])[2]/td[3]/div')).click();
```

But of no luck. It keeps ending up with error

```
[14:42:54] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Note: I'm able to click on the element manually and could see the element present & visible in DOM once the page loads. Also, Id's are auto generated. So, I wouldn't be able to use them.

Could anyone help in resolving this issue ?

Comment: Try `//table[2]//tr[contains(@role,"row") and contains(@data-boundview,"gridview")]`

Comment: <Page Loads>
browser.sleep(10000);
element(by.css("div[id^=StatusFilterPageId-placeholder]")).click();
browser.sleep(6000);

Could witness, even a simple click event isn't working in corresponding page with protractor selectors. Any idea why ? Only if we narrow down this issue, I believe we would be able to traverse into the table content present in the same page.

Comment: Issue has been identified Andersson. The particular page wasn't Angular and I'm supposed to include browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; in the page class if we are testing a non-Angular based website. With this being added, I'm able to access all the elements in the page now and perform required actions over the desired table.

Answer (score 0):

first xpath will point to table 2 and then you can use any strategy to move to a selected row or column.. you can chain to any number of elements e.g.
move to table2.row2.col3

```
element(by.xpath(("//tbody[@id='gridview-1057-body']")[2])) 
.element(by.something('second table row/col selector'))
.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting a specific element in a specific table I would suggest the following approach:

This code selects the second table and clicks on column 2 in row 1

```
// get second table
let table = element.all(by.css('table tbody')).get(1);

// get rows
let rows = table.all(by.tagName('tr'));

// get row1
rows.get(0)

  // get column2 of row 1
  .all(by.tagName('td'))
  .get(1)

  // click underlying div.
  .element(by.tagName('div'))
  .click();
```

You should make use of other locators than `xpath` because:

> - It's the slowest and most brittle locator strategy of all
> - Markup is very easily subject to change and therefore `xpath` locators  require a lot of maintenance
> - `xpath` expressions are unreadable and very hard to debug

reference => https://github.com/CarmenPopoviciu/protractor-styleguide#rule-06-never-use-xpath

Comment: Thanks Silvan. I have changed the approach of using xpath now and using CSS as suggested. Xpath seemed to be easy one to locate and I may end up writing only couple lines of code to perform the action. But, I agree xpath is brittle.

Comment: There is a problem using it. The page is developed with EXT JS. The array value of selector (by.css(table tbody)).get(4) changes very frequently depending upon the user action in UI. For ex.,Initially I find a table to be in array position (23) and all of sudden I need to click on a dropdown. This forms a new table structure in the DOM resulting in a change of array value of my initial table. My bad luck, there are no static unique value to all these tables being generated in the DOM.Table identification has to be generic which could be used for all scenarios.How could I mitigate this issue ?

Comment: I cannot follow your description of the table. Can you either update this question or create a new one for showing reproduction steps? I Understand you have some problem with dynamically created data. For helping you, best would be to describe a particular use-case.